# Scrolling to the bottom of page with invisible scrollbars

Tags: c#, .net

I use this code to remove my scrollbars:

```
        mainPanel = new Panel
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            AutoScroll = true,
            AutoSize = true,
        };

        mainPanel.AutoScroll = false;
        mainPanel.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        mainPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        mainPanel.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
        mainPanel.AutoScroll = true;
```

The issue I'm having is, before I hid my scrollbars I could use:

```
mainPanel.VerticalScroll.Value = mainPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
```

To scroll to the bottom of the page, this no longer works as the VerticalScroll.Maximum is set to 0.

My question now: How do I scroll to the bottom of the page with hidden scrollbars? (With code, manual scrolling works fine)

EDIT: I have found a solution:

```
mainPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, mainPanel.Height);
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: have you tried to set a different Maximum? to make the scrollbar not visible changing Visible should be enough.

Comment: @Gusman I have tried to set it back to the starting value (100), but my scrollbars will just reappear again.

Comment: And what happens if you don't change it to 0 before setting Visible to false?

Comment: @Gusman If I dont set it to 0, the scrollbars stay visible.

Comment: @Gusman The Thread you posted did point me in the right direction:

I use ' mainPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, mainPanel.Height);'

This works. Thanks.